# Where can I find this header file: libc.h

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c++

I am using an external library that has a header starting with:

```
/* Headers other than ISO C++, such as BSD and Posix.1 headers */

// define INCLUDE_LIBC to include <libc.h> if available
#ifdef INCLUDE_LIBC
#ifdef HAVE_LIBC_H
#ifndef INCLUDE_LIBC_H_AS_CXX
BEGIN_EXTERN_C
#endif
#include <libc.h>
#ifndef INCLUDE_LIBC_H_AS_CXX
END_EXTERN_C
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

When I use it in an iPad project (device, debug) it raises a compile error:

```
libc.h: No such file or directory
```

Where does `libc` exists in any of the frameworks that come with the iPhone SDK?  Any other suggestions on how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

**As far as I can see, libc.h doesn't exist in my SDK.**

Comment: so what shall I do to over this compiler error ,I need to add external library that call #include <libc.h> to my code , but it give error no such file or directory
 
I want to know under which framework will exist this header file

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? Can you show us the implementation than invokes the libc.h?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no such thing as libc.h. I've never seen such a thing. If libc.h existed, you'd expect to find a libc.c somewhere but you won't find that guy, either.

Instead, you must #include stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h, ... . These header files hold definitions and declarations for functions that have been compiled and archived into libc.lib (or whatever your system's library extension is).

It would be very handy if there ***were*** a libc.h: it would help when I forget to #include some header or other. And you can of course make your own header file that does nothing ***but*** #include stdio.h, stdint.h, and so on; and you can name it whatever you like, maybe even libc.h.

But a /usr/include/libc.h (say) doesn't exist and it never will.

-- pete

Comment: I tried to add #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> but the error still exist

Comment: @Ali, why did you edit your original question so that it now asks about "libc" rather than "libc.h"?  Do you still have the line "#include <libc.h>" in  your source file? If you do, then please delete that line. If the #include of libc.h is not there anymore, then please post (by copying from your source code and pasting into your post) all of the lines that are #include's. We'll straighten this out.

Comment: the line #include <libc.h> is in the external library not in my code , do u have any suggestion how to fix that or overide the checks the library made #ifdef INCLUDE_LIBC
#ifdef HAVE_LIBC_H
#ifndef INCLUDE_LIBC_H_AS_CXX
BEGIN_EXTERN_C
#endif
#include <libc.h>
#ifndef INCLUDE_LIBC_H_AS_CXX
END_EXTERN_C
#endif
#endif
#endif

Comment: @Ali, I apologize for blaming you for this puzzle. Questions: (1) What is the name of the file that has the line #include <libc.h>? That is, what is this "external library?" (2) Productions like "#ifdef INCLUDE_LIBC" suggest that there is some configuration process that has to be run before you start/started development; and perhaps a file named "config.h". Do you see anything like that?

Comment: @Ali, I think I just found out that development for iPhone is in the Objective-C language rather than just plain old C. That explains a lot of my confused obtuseness. Then, I see that there is an iPhone development forum: http://forums.oreilly.com/category/93/Head-First-iPhone-Development/ . Have you looked at that forum? It seems like a good place to ask your question also.

Comment: @Ali, I see now that the O'Reilly forum is really a forum for discussing the O'Reilly book "Head First iPhone Development." But there must be some iPhone dev groups around somewhere.

Comment: @Ali, please take a look at these pages. You answer will be there: http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/index.php and http://tinyurl.com/6krh8xa

Comment: @Ali, I see that you've already asked in at least one of the iPhone dev forums. I was going to suggest that you please take a look at these pages. I was hoping your answer would be there: http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/index.php and http://tinyurl.com/6krh8xa

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1083/ Click on libc-825.26.

You might consider commenting out that code, though, since it seems from the comment it is not required for that library.

This is a common sort of problem when cross-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the other answers saying that `libc.h` doesn't exist; it very much exists - on my system (x86_64 running OS X 10.9.2) at least - in `/usr/include/`. FWIW, here are the contents:

```
    /*
 * Copyright (c) 1999 Apple Computer, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_START@
 * 
 * This file contains Original Code and/or Modifications of Original Code
 * as defined in and that are subject to the Apple Public Source License
 * Version 2.0 (the 'License'). You may not use this file except in
 * compliance with the License. Please obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.opensource.apple.com/apsl/ and read it before using this
 * file.
 * 
 * The Original Code and all software distributed under the License are
 * distributed on an 'AS IS' basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, AND APPLE HEREBY DISCLAIMS ALL SUCH WARRANTIES,
 * INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, QUIET ENJOYMENT OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.
 * Please see the License for the specific language governing rights and
 * limitations under the License.
 * 
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_END@
 */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995 NeXT Computer, Inc. All Rights Reserved
 */

#ifndef _LIBC_H
#define _LIBC_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef  __STRICT_BSD__
#include <strings.h>
#include <varargs.h>
#else
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#endif

#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <mach/machine/vm_types.h>
#include <mach/boolean.h>
#include <mach/kern_return.h>

struct qelem {
        struct qelem *q_forw;
        struct qelem *q_back;
        char *q_data;
};

#include <sys/cdefs.h>

__BEGIN_DECLS
extern kern_return_t map_fd(int fd, vm_offset_t offset,
        vm_offset_t *addr, boolean_t find_space, vm_size_t numbytes);
__END_DECLS

#endif  /* _LIBC_H */
```

As for what one of the answers says, "if libc.h existed, you'd expect to find a libc.c somewhere", that's not generally true (although perhaps the poster didn't intend it the way I read it); once a .c file has been compiled into an object file, you can definitely chuck the .c file; otherwise closed-source software (as we know it today) wouldn't exist!